# I receive an Insert Into error with this code any solution?

Tags: sql, delphi

```pascal
if (conpassedt.text = '') or (regpassedt.text = '') or (regaccedt.text = '') or (regpassedt.text <> conpassedt.text) then
  begin
    showmessage('Please fill in all fields for input and confirm passwords match');
  end else
  begin
    DM.qryDB.sql.clear;
    DM.qrydb.sql.add('INSERT INTO tblUsers(AccountName, Password) ');
    DM.qrydb.sql.add('VALUES ("'+ regaccedt.text +'", "' + THashMD5.GetHashString(regpassedt.text) + '")');
    DM.qrydb.ExecSQL;
  end;
```

Comment: Please TAG your database. Also, share with us the whole text of the error you received.

Comment: Error msg : Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement

Comment: You would probably be better off using parameters by name instead of trying to manage the quoting. See [Bobby Tables](https://www.bobby-tables.com/delphi)  for the reason why.

Comment: Propably you need to use two single quotes ```''``` instead of one double quote ```"```, but to prevent SQL injection problems you should use SQL parameters!

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, your DB requires *single* quotes instead of *double* quotes on string literals, eg:

```pascal
DM.qrydb.sql.add('INSERT INTO tblUsers(AccountName, Password) ');
DM.qrydb.sql.add('VALUES (''' + regaccedt.text + ''', ''' + THashMD5.GetHashString(regpassedt.text) + ''')');
```

In which case, you *should* use `QuotedStr()` instead to handle quoting and escaping for you (which will better help you avoid SQL Injection attacks properly), eg:

```pascal
DM.qrydb.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO tblUsers (AccountName, Password) ');
DM.qrydb.SQL.Add('VALUES (' + QuotedStr(regaccedt.text) + ', ' + QuotedStr(THashMD5.GetHashString(regpassedt.text)) + ')');
```

Though, you really should use a *parameterized* query instead, and let the DB engine work out any necessary quoting and escaping that it needs, eg:

```pascal
DM.qrydb.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO tblUsers (AccountName, Password) ');
DM.qrydb.SQL.Add('VALUES (:PAccountName, :PPassword)');
DM.qrydb.ParamByName('PAccountName').AsString := regaccedt.text;
DM.qrydb.ParamByName('PPassword').AsString := THashMD5.GetHashString(regpassedt.text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Modern versions of Delphi with Firedac have overloaded versions of various SQL methods to allow removal of a lot of the boilerplate in your question. Also as already mentioned in comments use parameters vs constructing a string.

```
  FDQuery1.ExecSQL('INSERT INTO tblUsers(AccountName, Password) VALUES (:AccountName, :Password);',
                   [regaccedt.text,THashMD5.GetHashString(regpassedt.text)],
                   [ftWideString,ftWideString]);
```